# POST method not inserting data into database table

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mamp

I'm trying to play around with databases and inserting data dynamically with php.
At the moment I have a form with 'post' method and everything seems logical to me but it isn't inserting the data into the table.

Code is attached below, would appreciate if someone could point me into the right direction.

**index.php:**

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">

<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" required>

<label for="breed">Breed</label>
<input type="text" name="breed">

<label for="age">Age</label>
<input type="text" name="age">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<?php

require "connect.php";

if('submit') {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $breed = $_POST['breed'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

    $newdog = mysqli_query('INSERT INTO `dogs`(`name`, `breed`, `age`) VALUES ([$name],[$breed],[$age)');

    if ($newdog) {
        echo "$name has been added to the database";
    } else {
        echo "$name has not been added to database.";
    };
};

?>
```

**connect.php:**

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'max', 'password', 'db_test');

?>
```

Comment: Please use *prepared statements*, your code is open to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Change `if('submit') {`

**TO**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//check if it is set

}
```

Also change this line:

`$newdog = mysqli_query('INSERT INTO`dogs`(`name`,`breed`,`age`) VALUES ([$name],[$breed],[$age)');`

**TO**

`$newdog = mysqli_query($connect, 'INSERT INTO`dogs`(`name`,`breed`,`age`) VALUES ($name,$breed,$age)');//remove square bracktes and add connection variable`

Your code is very well vulnerable to SQL injection

Using prepared statements,

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO dogs (`name`, `breed`, `age`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $breed, $age);
if($stmt->execute() == true){
   echo 'Saved';
} else {
   echo 'Error '. $stmt->error;
 }
```

Comment: its not working so far, even with the changes you suggested. I understand its vulnerable, but I want to get it working first before worrying about security. Thanks for the help so far

Comment: Thanks @akintude , it doesn't work yet but I appreciate your effort to make my code secure :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

require "connect.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $breed = $_POST['breed'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

    $newdog = mysqli_query($connect, 'INSERT INTO dogs(name, breed, age) VALUES ("'.$name.'","'.$breed.'","'.$age.'")');

    if ($newdog) {
        echo "$name has been added to the database";
    } else {
        echo "$name has not been added to database.";
    };
};

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Own answer: Figured it out, I had to configure PHPStorm to use MAMP Apache server instead of the internal server since that one apparently doesn't like $_POST[] requests